# Tensorflow classification program with multiple parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

Just a beginner with Tensorflow.

I am trying to run a classification model with multiple numpy arrays as input with two possible categories that it would be classified it into. I am not able to get it run. I tried looking at the tutorials and other threads but I haven't gotten any ideas. Does anyone know how to create a model that accepts multiple parameters as arrays?

feedmag feedlat feedtime and feedlong are numpy arrays

Here is the error message:

label_ids
    format(labels.dtype))

ValueError: Labels dtype should be integer. Instead got .

Here is my code.

```
for i in range (0,34):
    labels = np.append(labels,int(1));
for i in range (0,34):
    labels = np.append(labels,int(2));
    feature = {'magnitude':  feedmag,
            'time':  feedtime,
            'latitude': feedlat,
            'longitude':  feedlong}

 my_feature_columns = []
 for key in feature.keys():
 my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key))

classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
   feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
    # Two hidden layers of 10 nodes each.
   hidden_units=[10, 10],
   n_classes = 4;
    # The model must choose between 3 classes.
    optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
  learning_rate=0.1,

  l1_regularization_strength=0.001))
with tf.Session() as session:
    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
  feature,
  labels,
  num_epochs=1,
  shuffle=True,
  batch_size=33)

    test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        feature,
        labels,
        num_epochs=1,
        shuffle=False,
        batch_size=33)
classifier.train(input_fn = lambda: train_input_fn)
print('starting')
print(classifier.evaluate(
  input_fn=test_input_fn, steps = 33))
print("ending")
print(tf.VERSION)
```

Comment: changed to classifier.train(input_fn = train_input_fn) getting another error               InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): assertion failed: [Label IDs must < n_classes] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:] [x (dnn/head/ToFloat:0) = ] [[2][2][2]...] [y (dnn/head/assert_range/Const:0) = ] [2]

Comment: changed it a bit more errors ValueError: Labels dtype should be integer. Instead got <dtype: 'float64'>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
classifier.train(input_fn = lambda: train_input_fn)
```

to...

```
classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)
```

Explanation: `train_input_fn` is transforming numpy arrays to tensors (which is what tensorflow expects), while `lambda: train_input_fn` is a function that returns a `train_input_fn` function.

Comment: The first error is gone but I am now getting another error InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): assertion failed: [Label IDs must < n_classes] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:] [x (dnn/head/ToFloat:0) = ] [[2][2][2]...] [y (dnn/head/assert_range/Const:0) = ] [2]

Comment: @NathanZhang you didn't provide `labels` and other arrays to reproduce it. I think you should also fix indentation (in the line with `feature`)

Comment: @NathanZhang set `n_classes` parameter of `DNNClassifier`. By default, it's binary

Comment: yea indentation is good in the actual code and my labels code is for i in range (0,34):
    labels = np.append(labels,1);
for i in range (0,34):
    labels = np.append(labels,2)

Comment: @NathanZhang don't post the code into comments, just fix the code in question

Comment: yea got it thanks, I am appending 1 and 2 to the labels but it says that im appending floats

Comment: Anyway, your main issue is `n_classes` as I wrote above

Comment: I changed that and im not getting errors for that but im getting this  ValueError: Labels dtype should be integer. Instead got <dtype: 'float64'>.

Comment: it is not solved yet, i;m getting another error  ValueError: Labels dtype should be integer. Instead got <dtype: 'float64'> i will accept it after there are no errors